# Blend/VS designer support for adding complex content based on boolean property

Tags: xaml, expression-blend, designer, data-visualization

I have my own derived WPF DataVisualization chart control and within that control, I have a boolean property that the designer can set which in turn creates and adds a line series to that chart control.

Now the problem is that I can easily create the line series object within the chart when the designer sets that property, but I also need to insert a complex xaml segment into the .xaml file associated with that newly created line series. Is there a way to automatically insert that xaml code into the xaml file when that boolean property is set in the blend designer?

Thanks

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the only properties you can expose are individual attributes on existing elements. There is no provision to insert new elements *based on attribute changes*. You only add elements by inserting new controls etc.

### Create an extension for Expression Blend:

To do what you want you would need to create a plugin for Expression Blend. If you are in a position to do that then anything is possible (add entirely new tools and properties for instance):
[Try this link for starters](http://blog.timmykokke.com/archive/2010/03/21/building-extensions-for-expression-blend-4-using-mef.aspx)